# Programmatically changing the height of a collectionView to be proportional to the View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I programmatically change the height of a collectionView to be proportional to the original view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please link them as IBOutlet and try:

1. Get *height* with

`let h = self.<originalView>.frame.size.height`

2. Set *height* with

`self.<collectionView>.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h)`

(obviously replacing a, b , c by the required values)

Comment: Please up and mark as answer if this issue is closed